# Sqoop failing to import MySQL to Hadoop, throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, classnotfoundexception

I installed Sqoop 1.4.6 and tried to import some data from MySQL 5.6.29 into Hadoop version 2.7.2 with the following command:

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://<server_name>:3306/<dbname> --username <user-name> --password <password> --m 1 --table <table-name> --target-dir <hadoop-target-folder>`

Then, I'm getting following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class <ClassName> not found 
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class <ClassName> not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getInputClass(DBConfiguration.java:403)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.createDBRecordReader(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:237)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.createRecordReader(DBInputFormat.java:263)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:515)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:758)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class <ClassName> not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
... 12 more
```

There might have been a similar question but I didn't find answers...

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: which MySQL driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using the JDBC MySQL Connector version 5.1.38 i.e. mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar and copied it to the $SQOOP_HOME/libexec/lib directory. I'm on Mac so I installed Sqoop using brew.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the jar: 
`scoop codegen --connect "jdbc:mysql://example.com/sqoop" --username sqoop --password sqoop --table tbl`

Look for the line in the output: Writing jar file:

```
/tmp/sqoop-abe/compile/4182409b0f559d7259a32a950627e1aa/tbl.jar
```

Use the above jar in your import commmand:

```
sqoop import -fs local -jt local -libjars /tmp/sqoop-abe/compile/4182409b0f559d7259a32a950627e1aa/tbl.jar --connect "jdbc:mysql://example.com/sqoop" --username sqoop --password sqoop --table tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that when using the LocalJobRunner to do the import job it cannot load the jar generate by sqoop.

Solution 1. change hadoop to run in the one-node cluster mode, http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html.

Solution 2. first generate the jar file, then use the -libjars parameter.